# size of struct with bitfields

Tags: c, struct

```
    static struct{
            unsigned a:5;
            unsigned b:5;
            unsigned c:5;
            unsigned d:5;
    }v={1,2,3,4};

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d",v.a,v.b,v.c,v.d,sizeof(v));
```

**Output** is : 1 2 3 4 4

Can someone explain why is the size of this struct 4 ? Shouldn't it be 16 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using 20 bits which fit nicely in 4 bytes. No need for 16 bytes.

#### EDIT

I think it is actually *required* that they be packed like that:

> 6.7.2.1
>
> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large
> enough to hold a bit- ﬁeld.  If enough space remains, a bit-ﬁeld that
> immediately follows another bit-ﬁeld in a structure **shall be packed
> into adjacent bits** of the same unit

Answer (score 6):

Bitfields packs the bit, so your 20 bits fits nicely in a 32-bit int, and not four different ints.